# Playstation Vita hardware specs

Tags: ps-vita

Do you know which are the full hardware specs of Playstation Vita? Are that specs already frozen and officially available?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Official Spefications have been released by Sony, at TGS 2011

- Model number: PCH-1000 series
- CPU: ARM® Cortex™-A9 core (4 core)
- GPU: SGX543MP4+
- Main memory: 512MB
- VRAM: 128MB
- External Dimensions: Approx. 182.0 x 18.6 x 83.5mm (width x height x depth) (tentative, excludes largest projection)
- Weight Approx: 279g (3G/Wi-Fi model), 260g (Wi-Fi model)
- Screen: 5 inches (16:9), 960 x 544, Approx. 16 million colours, OLED, Multi touch screen (capacitive type)
- Rear touch pad: Multi touch pad (capacitive type)
- Cameras: Front camera, Rear camera; Frame rate: 120fps@320x240(QVGA), 60fps@640x480(VGA); Resolution: Up to 640x480(VGA)
- Sound: Built-in stereo speakers, built-in microphone
- Sensors: Six-axis motion sensing system (three-axis gyroscope, three-axis accelerometer), Threeaxis electronic compass
- Location: Built-in GPS (3G/Wi-Fi model only), Wi-Fi location service support
- Keys/Switches: PS button, power button, directional buttons (Up/Down/Right/Left), action buttons (Triangle, Circle, Cross, Square), shoulder buttons (Right/Left), right stick, left stick, START button, SELECT button, volume buttons (+/-)
- Wireless communications: Mobile network connectivity (3G/Wi-Fi model only), 3G modem (data communication): HSDPA/HSUPA *specification for Japanese region, IEEE 802.11b/g/n (n = 1x1)(Wi-Fi) (Infrastructure mode/Ad-hoc mode), Bluetooth® 2.1+EDR ?A2DP/AVRCP/HSP?
- Slots/Ports: PlayStation®Vita card slot, memory card slot, SIM card slot (3G/Wi-Fi model only), multi-use port (for USB data communication, DC IN, Audio [Stereo Out / Mono In], Serial data communication), headset jack (Stereo mini jack) (for Audio [Stereo Out / Mono In]), accessory port
- Power: Built-In Lithium-ion Battery: DC3.7V 2200mA, AC adaptor: DC 5V
- Operating environment temperature: 5??35?
- Supported AV content format: Music - MP3 MPEG-1/2 Audio Layer 3, MP4 (MPEG-4 AAC), WAVE (Linear PCM). Videos - MPEG-4 Simple Profile (AAC), H.264/MPEG-4 AVC High/Main/Baseline Profile (AAC). Photos - JPEG (Exif 2.2.1), TIFF, BMP, GIF, PNG

PlayStation Vita has a battery life of between three and five hours during gameplay.

The PlayStation Vita WiFi model will be priced at ¥24,980 (£206.40 / $324.80), while the 3G model will be priced at ¥29,980 (£247.70 / $389.80) with 3G support provided by NTT Docomo.
Via [Digital Spy](http://www.digitalspy.co.uk/gaming/news/a340291/playstation-vita-full-specifications-released-tokyo-game-show-2011.html)

Answer (score 4):

What I could find:

- Quad-core ARM A9 processor, Cortex
- SGX543MP4+ GPU
- OLED touchscreen (resolution 960 x 544 pixel, 220ppi – 5inch display)
- Touchpad (rear)
- Dual analogue control sticks
- Digital D-pad and 6 buttons
- Six-axis motion sensing technology
- Built-in microphone + speakers
- Built-in camera
- Wi-Fi, 3G on 3G model
- Dimensions: 182.0 x 18.6 x 83.5mm
- Price: $250 for Wifi, $299 for Wifi/3G

So yeah, pretty awesome specs for a portable, no?
Windows 8 supports the ARM CPU as well.

EDIT: This was announced on the E3 convention. So, it's pretty official.

Comment: Six-axis motion sensing exists out of an 3D Gyro, Compass and Accelerometer. Also it has a front and back facing camera where the back facing will mostly be used for AR.

Comment: Quad core CPU and quad core GPU. It seems impressive!

Comment: To be honest it is quite weak – phone hardware is accelerating very quickly and sooner or later phone hardware will exceed Vita's capabilities.